# Understanding struct.unpack python

Tags: python, byte, unpack

```
test = struct.unpack('>%dH' % 1, '\x00\x44')
```

Is confusing me. I thought it means take the first 8 bytes and treat them as a double then take the next two and treat them as a short, and do all of that one time. But it means something else and I can't figure out what. It seems to realize that there is no double present and converts those two bytes to one number.

This code

```
test = struct.unpack('>1dH' , '\x00\x44')
```

Throws an error because it's expecting to find a double...

Can anyone tell me what the difference between these two are?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'>%dH' % 1` is equivalent to `'>1H'`.

```
>>> '>%dH' % 1
'>1H'
```

`'>%dH' % 1` is using [old-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) to replace the `%d` with `1`.

So the struct format is specifying a big-endian two-byte unsigned short.